# Scala: Using Sets for (non - primitive) co-odinate values

Tags: scala, set, scala-collections

I'm using integer coordinates for hex grids as follows:

```
object Cood
{ 
  val up = Cood(0, 2)
  val upRight = Cood(1, 1)
  val downRight = Cood(1, -1)
  val down = Cood(0, - 2)
  val downLeft = Cood(-1, -1)
  val upLeft = Cood(- 1, 1)    
  val dirns: List[Cood] = List[Cood](up, upRight, downRight, down, downLeft, upLeft) 
}
case class Cood(x: Int, y: Int)
{
  def +(operand: Cood): Cood = Cood(x + operand.x, y + operand.y)
  def -(operand: Cood): Cood = Cood(x - operand.x, y - operand.y)
  def *(operand: Int): Cood = Cood(x * operand, y * operand)
}
```

Hexs and Sides both have coordinate values. Every Hex has 6 sides but some sides will be shared by 2 Hexs. Eg Hex(2, 2) and its upper neighbour Hex(2, 6) share Side(2, 4). So I want to apply set operations something like this:

```
val hexCoods: Set[Cood] = ... some code
val sideCoods: Set[Cood] = hexCoods.flatMap(i => Cood.dirns.map(_ + i).toSet)
```

But if I do this Cood will be treated as a reference type and the duplicate co-ordinates won't be stripped out. Is there any way round this?

Comment: Sets do not contain duplicates. Show us some example input and output to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @sschaef I see the Set Class is treating Cood as if it were a value type. Presumably that's because its a case class?

Comment: No, Cood is a reference type. But the compiler generates an `equals` and `hashCode` method for it, which should ensure that there can not be duplicates in a `Set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it?

```
scala> Set.empty + Cood(1,1) + Cood(1,2) + Cood(1,1)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Cood] = Set(Cood(1,1), Cood(1,2))
```

Like @sschaef pointed out in the comments, case classes have automatically-generated `equals` and `hashCode` methods, which implement structural equality rather than just comparing identity. This means that you shouldn't get duplicates in your set, and sure enough the set in my test didn't have a duplicate entry.